# Does LaTeX allow you to rapidly switch your document layout to fit editor choices?

Tags: article

After my last (and first) question, I've been given some information about medical articles.

I looked at my professor doing some case reports. He uses Word to write the entire document; when he decides the journal to mail the document he searches for that journal specifications such as font and sizes, structure, bibliography rules, …
At this point, he adjusts the document, add the bibliography and so on, following the editor guidelines. It's a big waste of time, and each journal has specific and different rules that must be applied.

Here I come back to my first question. Providing some journals do not even have a LaTeX section (templates, rules, accepted formats, … ), is it possible to easily switch layout based on their needs?

Comment: You're describing the *class* of a document.  Yes, you might say LaTeX was built for this use.  Many journals do provide LaTeX classes for their articles.  But those that do not, probably want submissions in Word.

Answer (score 14):

It is certainly easier to apply such global changes in LaTeX than in Word as LaTeX is really designed for that use. However as in Word the ease of applying global style changes depends greatly on the use of suitable commands within the document.

If you change

```
\documentclass{article}
```

to

```
\documentclass{some-journal-class}
```

then the definition of (for example) section commands will be redefined to use fonts and styling required by the journal. However this redefinition only affects the document if the document has

```
\section{Introduction}
.....
```

If the document has

```
\vspace{1cm}
\begingroup
\fontsize{20pt}{30pt}\bf
Introduction\par
\endgroup
\vspace{.5cm}
```

then changing the definition of `\section` doesn't help and the document will still have a 20pt bold "heading". The same applies to setting page widths, manually forcing line breaks etc. So basically the *cleaner* the markup in the document is using higher level constructs, the easier it is to change the typographic style without having to edit the markup.

Answer (score 7):

Given that LaTeX is programmable, this is 100% possible. One of the benefits / possibilities of LaTeX is to clearly separate the content (structure) from the layout.

As for how to do it, whether or not it is *easy* depends on your skills and on the complexity of the layouts requested by the journals (given submissions are in Word, they couldn't be that complex...). What you would have to do is:

- Define a set of generic commands that will be used to structure your articles. Rather than starting from scratch, start from the `article` class (that's exacly what it was made for) and define what is missing for your particular field, if anything;
- (Re)implement the commands for each journal, adapting them to the requested layout. Personally, I would probably define a class per journal, so that all you have to do is change the `\documentclass` of an article to format it to the journal's specifications.

One final thought: check beforehand that your journals accept submissions in pdf format, which is unfortunately not always the case. [As some have said](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110949/10102), there are a couple of journals that force bad typography :(

Comment: Is there a guide to understand commands and class file variables?

Comment: Moreover...if a journal wants the file to be submitted in word, is it better to write the file in word then to convert it?

Comment: For your question about understanding how to write a class, you should start by reading (LaTeX2e for class and package writers)[http://latex-project.org/guides/clsguide.pdf‎] and `article.cls`.

Comment: For you second comment, I personally wouldn't try to write in LaTeX and then convert to word; the conversion can be painful, and if you're not used to LaTeX to the point that it makes writing much easier for you, I don't see the benefit of the hassle.

Comment: So essentially you think it's better to choose your journal before starting the writing process...

Comment: @alberto Yes. If the journal requires Word, I wouldn't bother doing it in LaTeX

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately "rapidly" is a kind of relative term. The strength of LaTeX is that it separates content from form, and should be able to assign a semantic markup to every element in your document. To the extent that your document uses that markup, it's relatively simple to make changes to the formatting and ensure consistency.

Furthermore, provided you are using a BibTeX file for your bibliography, reformatting citations and references to a particular style is also relatively easy, especially if the style is fairly standard or someone has already created a bibliography style for it.

That being said, certain requirements may require some work to implement depending on what they are.

Answer (score 4):

If your journals provide LaTeX document classes and style files for bibtex, switching requires minimal changes. Usually you only need to change the document class, bibliography style and maybe some data in the header (e.g., `\address` instead of `\affilitation`). If the linewidth is different, you may need to break equations differently.

Concerning journals that don't accept LaTeX: well, conversion can take time then. However, usually you shouldn't put too much effort into mimicking a journals layout to the last detail. They all have copy editors and typesetting systems, and will mess up your manuscript anyway.

Comment: Maybe mimicking it's easy, but the journals you lastly mentioned usually want your documents in Word format, this is the problem.

Comment: @alberto Maybe have a look at [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/index.html). Converts all kinds of markup formats into each other.